# No firebase.app.App instance is currently initialized. Angular 6 sign in with phone error

Tags: typescript, firebase, authentication, angular6

I've initialized firebase app, and tried every possible thing, but I'm unable to remove this error. I'm trying firebase sign in with phone number authentication.

Below is my app.component.ts file:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  applicationVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container', {
    'size': 'invisible',
    'callback': function(response) {
    },
    'expired-callback': function() {
    }
    });
   signIn(phone) {

    firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phone, this.applicationVerifier)
    .then(function(confirmationResult) {
      var code = window.prompt("Please enter your code");
      return confirmationResult.confirm(code);
    })
    .then(function(result) {
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log("error", error);
    });
   }
  }
```

Please help resolve this error.

Answer (score 11):

I was having the same issue. Calling `firebase.initializeApp` solved it for me.

In the Component's ngOnInit() function add the following line before you create the RecaptchaVerifier.

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: Adding in ngOninit didn't work for me.
Add in app.modules.ts fixed. https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/556#issuecomment-250094088

Answer (score 1):

the correct way is to:

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase,'utoopie')
```

to

```
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase)
```

in the app.module.ts

for more info check this Github convo [here](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/issues/556#issuecomment-302882027).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this Issue:

Make sure you have initialized AngularFireModule in `app.module.ts`:
`AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseCred)`

If you're still having the issue- `ng serve` again.

If you're still having the issue load AngularFireAuthModule into your `app.module.ts` by:

```
import {AngularFireAuthModule} from '@angular/fire/auth';

 imports: [
    AngularFireAuthModule
  ]
```

and `ng serve` again.

This worked for me.